# How to import local XML files by using Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

As the title described, I tried several ways to import local XML files into my code and want to display them through a table. But no one can do it, and someone said I need to establish a server then I can do it by using Ajax, some said the browsers has security feature prevent you from accessing the local files. But I just want to access it locally， I've been looking for answers this whole afternoon. So if there is anyone knows a way, please tell me how to do it, better with an example, I will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can establish a local lightweight server. And if you want them for testing you can always embed them.

Comment: How do you access your current script? Do you just open it in a browser using file protocol(usually double click the file and open in a browser) or from a server using http?

Comment: As others have told you, this will be easy if you retrieve the file from a server (one line of code). You should tell us more about your setup so we can help you do this.